# Echo the result

Tags: php, json, bitcoin

I am trying to use the coin payments API documentation of PHP to get a callback address for BTC. I get the result as nothing while the result should be like this(JSON):-

```
{  
   "error":"ok",
   "result":{  
      "address":"1BitcoinAddress",
      "pubkey":"",
      "dest_tag":100,
   }
}
```

But I get nothing to see my code:-

```
class CoinPaymentsAPI {
private $private_key = '';
private $public_key = '';
private $ch = null;

public function Setup($private_key, $public_key) {
    $this->private_key = $private_key;
    $this->public_key = $public_key;
    $this->ch = null;
}

public function GetCallbackAddress($currency = 'BTC', $ipn_url = '') {      
    $req = array(
        'currency' => $currency,
        'ipn_url' => $ipn_url,
    );
    return $this->api_call('get_callback_address', $req);
    echo $this
}

?>
```

help me, please

Comment: the echo will not work after return

Comment: You seem to be missing the closing curly brace for the class definition. Indenting the contents of your class is also standard to aid with identifying the matching braces.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon when attempting to echo it out and you need to close your functions with a curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Please echo `response data` by using `json_encode()` function as I updated your function.

```
public function GetCallbackAddress($currency = 'BTC', $ipn_url = '') {      
    $req = array(
        'currency' => $currency,
        'ipn_url' => $ipn_url,
    );
    $resp = $this->api_call('get_callback_address', $req);
    echo json_encode($resp);die();
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting now?

Comment: It responds nothing

Comment: It means $this->api_call('get_callback_address', $req); response nothing.

Comment: It is responding nothing

Comment: I mean the echo part

Comment: I want to echo the call back address which is generated

Comment: Can u email me at ana3rb121@Gmail.com we will discuss there

Answer (score 0):

You can't **echo** after **return**, if you wants to **echo** something then **return** should be after that and on other-side, why you are **echoing** the all objects. Its seems not correct.

If below code will return array data then you should use code like:--

```
echo json_encode($this->api_call('get_callback_address', $req));
```